# Sending Simple Apex Post Request

Tags: apex, json, post

I have narrowed down why my apex post request is not sending to an external API. For some reason the JSON data that I serialize and send is wrong but everything works when I test it using Postman.

```
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('apilink.com');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'token'); 

    String body = '{"gift_id": "12345", "recipients": [{"email": 
    "test@email.com", "fist_name": "Test", "last_name": "test", 
    "message": "Testing post", "type": "email"}]}';
    req.setBody(JSON.serialize(body));
    HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
```

I get error code 400 which means bad data is being sent.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. Can you please share the rest (no pun intended) of the pertinent code (you can genericize any sensitive info, like a specific endpoint) - as in, are you calling `req.setHeader`, `req.setMethod`, etc.?  You can [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/347312/edit) your question to add any info.

Comment: Added @Moonpie. Thanks!

Comment: @Ken not sure if this is a typo, but why is there `JSON.serialize` twice in the code? How r u building the body string? Looks like the string body is correctly formatted in json, try sending the string directly in the request body param

Comment: @Shamina yup it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (Noob mistake).... Did not need to serialize the JSON data. Thanks everyone.